# access array struct by index solidity

Tags: arrays, struct, solidity, contract

I would access the struct array by index in the following require statement but i have the error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAuZC.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the require you are assigning non comparing, try using == instead of =

Comment: You're right. Thank you so much!